# Force MessageBox.Show to display on top

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5, topmost

I have a simple winforms appl which will notify me when to add notes to my ticket. The problem I face is that when the application is minimised the messagebox doesnt show in front of all the other windows and programs I have open.

The code I have is:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Add some notes to your current ticket?",
      "Add Notes",
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);


     if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes) {
      Timer tm;
      tm = new Timer();

      tm.Interval = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
      tm.Tick += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

      string pastebuffer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
      pastebuffer = "### Edited on " + pastebuffer + " by " + txtUsername.Text + " ###";
      Clipboard.SetText(pastebuffer);

      tm.Start();
     } else if (result1 == DialogResult.No) {
      //do something else
     }
```

My understanding is that i need to add `TopMost = True`. But i cannot see where to add that in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you show your `MessageBox` set the `TopMost` property on your main form to `true`. The `MessageBox` will be modal to the top most main form making the `MessageBox` *top most*.

After the `MessageBox` has been shown you can easily set the `TopMost` property to false again.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true; // Here.

    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Add some notes to your current ticket?",
    "Add Notes",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    this.TopMost = false; // And over here.

    if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes) {
        Timer tm;
        tm = new Timer();

        tm.Interval = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        tm.Tick += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

        string pastebuffer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        pastebuffer = "### Edited on " + pastebuffer + " by " + txtUsername.Text + " ###";
        Clipboard.SetText(pastebuffer);

        tm.Start();
    }
    else if (result1 == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this: >>>>   `        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TopMost = true;
        }`

Comment: That will make all dialog forms in your application to be topmost.

Comment: It does not work, if the main form is minimised, the messagebox.show doesnt show when i am eg, web browsing..

Answer (score 3):

try this **MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification** :

```
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(some text, "ATENCIÓN",   MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
```